# Client Interaction in WebForms

Tags: c#, webforms

What way is standard/ recommended to do the following:

When a user raises the Page_Command "Save" or "Send," I want to run a method.  If the method returns false, I want to send the user back to the page and display a message.

All of the data they entered in the form should still be there.  The message would have a button that reads, "Send Anyway/ Regardless."  If they click it, it will send.

I know I could do this via a webservice and jQuery, but I am asking how I would do this via WebForms.

Here is my basic code:

```
protected void Page_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{   
    if ( e.CommandName == "Save" || e.CommandName == "Send" )
    {
        // run method
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to ViewState, that will just work.

Comment: @SLaks Could you, by chance, show me an example of how it would work using my simple code sample above, please?

Comment: @SLaks regarding this subject, is there a way to "return false" on my `Page_Command` in your to stop any further processing?  I have google'd this to no avail.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems I can simply use "return".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this.

One option might be to a button with the text "Save", and another with the text "Send anyway". Make the second button invisible to begin with, and the first visible.

When the first button is clicked, it should run the validation-logic. If validation succeeds, submit - otherwise, hide the first button, and set the other one to visible.

When / if the second button is clicked, the submit is performed without validation.

**Update:**

With some minor modifications, you should be able to do something like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" 
            ID="myFirstButton"
            OnClick="SubmitWithValidation" />

<asp:Button runat="server" 
            ID="mySecondButton"
            Visible="False"
            OnClick="SubmitData" />
```

Code:

```
protected void SubmitWithValidation(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ValidateMyData())
    {
            SubmitData(sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
        mySecondButton.Visible = true;
        myFirstButton.Visible = false;
    }
}

private bool ValidateMyData()
{
    // Validate stuff

    return isValid;
}

private void SubmitData(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // Logic to submit your data here
}
```

Comment: That is a good idea.  Do you have any example code so as how to achieve the following feats (?):  "If validation succeeds, submit - otherwise, hide the first button, and set the other one to visible." and "When / if the second button is clicked, the submit is performed without validation."

Comment: I've added a simple (untested) example, hope it's enough to help you out. :)

Comment: Thank you for your update!  I will review that; I am sure it will help.  Have a great weekend, Kjartan.